# How to rename multiple json object values in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data like this

```
[{'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__blackbox_exporter', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '0.19.0', 'new_version': '0.20.0'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__calico', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '3.21.4', 'new_version': '3.22.1'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__consul_template', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '0.25.1', 'new_version': '0.28.0'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__container_linux', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '3033.2.3', 'new_version': '3033.2.4'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__coredns', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.8.6', 'new_version': '1.9.1'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__cost-model', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.90.1', 'new_version': '1.91.2'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__data_plane_availability', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.21.3-alpine', 'new_version': '1.21.6-alpine'}, {'name': 'kubernetes-cluster__dellhw_exporter', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.11.0', 'new_version': '1.12.0'}]
```

The required data:

```
[{'name': 'blackbox_exporter', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '0.19.0', 'new_version': '0.20.0'}, {'name': 'calico', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '3.21.4', 'new_version': '3.22.1'}, {'name': 'consul_template', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '0.25.1', 'new_version': '0.28.0'}, {'name': 'container_linux', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '3033.2.3', 'new_version': '3033.2.4'}, {'name': 'coredns', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.8.6', 'new_version': '1.9.1'}, {'name': 'cost-model', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.90.1', 'new_version': '1.91.2'}, {'name': 'data_plane_availability', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.21.3-alpine', 'new_version': '1.21.6-alpine'}, {'name': 'dellhw_exporter', 'projects': ['kubernetes-cluster'], 'old_version': '1.11.0', 'new_version': '1.12.0'}]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing you need to modify is the value associated with the name. Perhaps you could use a for loop to modify that value for each element?

```py
for item in my_list:
    item[name] = item[name].removeprefix("kubernetes-cluster__")
```